# How to delete the intersecting part of two objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, pathfinder

As you can see in my image there are two circles kept on the hexagon. I want to know how do I delete the intersecting part of circle and hexagon which i marked in yellow ovals..??

[image]

Comment: Its the first icon in pathfinder window you have open.

Comment: i didn't get it...please elaborate..!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Unite` in the `Pathfinder` panel

[image]

or

you could use the shape Builder tool
[image]

They work differently unite would be easier for this task.
select the objects and click the unite button in the pathfinder panel. (`window > pathfinder`)

to use shapebuilder first select the objects then drag the tool over the parts you want to combined (conversely alt/opt drag to eliminate areas from shape)

Answer (score 0):

Provided the hexagon is a single, closed path:

- select the hexagon and both of the circles with the black arrow tool
  (<kbd>V</kbd>);
- click on the top left icon in the `Pathfinder` palette (`Unite`).

That's all.