# How to select a small portion of an image in illustrator cs6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

Suppose, two lines intersects each other as '+' like symbol.

Now i want to delete the extended portion of '+' and want to make it as 'T' shape.

But when i select the extended portion of a line, whole line is selected.

**So i want to know that, is there any way to select a portion intentionally having any size that may be so much small or big in adobe illustrator?**

Comment: Learn Pathfinder, Scissors, Add/Remove Anchor Point tool

Comment: thank u . but i will be happy more if u answered specificly about my example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete the intersecting part of two objects?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31580/how-to-delete-the-intersecting-part-of-two-objects)

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on the situation, but the most generic answer is to use shape builder.

1. Select the lines you want to participate in the cutting and cut.
2. Activate the shape builder tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Click or drag on line you do not want to keep.

   [image: trim]

   **Image 1**: Trim lines using shape builder.

This all depends a bit on your base understanding of how illustrator works. Direct selection suggested by @Avery_illson might work if your line is already split naturally at that point. But illustrator does not do so automatically just because 2 lines cross. Other options incude:

- Scissors tool
- **Object → Path → Divide Objects Below**

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is Direct Selection tool which should be <kbd>A</kbd> hot key. You can also use the Lasso Tool which is <kbd>Q</kbd> hotkey.