# Cut path at intersections

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pathfinder

So I have the following

[image: normal]

and I would like to remove the lines inside of the circle. I've tried the scissors tool, joining them then using the scissors, and outlining them using the pathfinder window then using scissors.

[image]

Comment: Expand, Divide, Delete middle bits, done.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to make it too complicated. It really can be very simple.

You could use the Add Anchor Point tool to add two anchor points to the straight lines, then use the Direct Section tool to delete the parts of the line and any remaining anchors you want.

[image: Animation showing deletion of lines]

Comment: Screencast-O-Matic? (Oh the humanity!) Have you tried [Open Broadcaster Studio](https://obsproject.com) or even [Microsoft Expression Encoder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27870)? Both are free to use with good output quality – and no watermarks. Expression Encoder has a 10 minute limit in the free version but that's usually plenty for most uses anyhow...

Comment: Motion screen capture is not something I do very often, and I was on another PC, and didn't want to install any software. Of course, I'll take a look at your recommendations, thanks.

Comment: @BANG for motion screen capture I recommend [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) more. It also has file sharing and productivity tools

Comment: It's 2022 now. Current best screen capture is [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/). free, simple, open source.

Answer (score 0):

Using the join and outline tools, then using the eraser, I've got it. This is such a basic task, Adobe should really make this simpler.

Anyway, here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: important note: you have to join BEFORE you outline

Comment: Adobe has made it simpler, use shapebuilder with`alt` pressed [see this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38779/how-to-select-a-small-portion-of-an-image-in-illustrator-cs6/58568#58568). Besides you can just fill the circle with white for the same result with even less effort, if you need it transparent then use the transparency options to knockout.

Answer (score 0):

Make two closed paths with appropriately thick strokes and no fill; first a triangle and then a circle on top:

[image: Simple shapes]

Duplicate the circle layer and place it at the top of the layer stack:

[image: Two circles and a triangle]

Make the triangle and the bottom circle paths active:

[image: Active paths]

Then go to Window > Pathfinder... If you're OK with just getting rid of *only the appearance* of the inside lines, you can simply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click on the 'Minus Front' button:

[image: Minus Front]

That produces this result:

[image: Compound Shape]

If you need the paths inside the circle to be actually gone – just click 'Minus Front' without the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier... Then if needed you can select the remaining shape and the circle and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to create a single compound path:

[image: Compound Path]