# AI-radial comic effect, using shape to minus path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

What's the efficient way to make the comic lines substracted from figure as shown in pic?

**method 1)** I made 1 effect line ctrl DDDD, then using shape builder tool to delete the path touching the green figure,but too many lines. I **do not** wish to expand appearance to make into shape as it is easier to edit path line.

**method 2)** I can also use a masking shape to mask the lines
[image]
Any better workflow steps? thanks guys

Comment: Have you tried Opacity Mask?

Comment: YOu can also drag select the subtraction, either as a box shape by holding ctrl+ alt to do multiple in one time or just alt+dag for sqiggle delete (or you cna doubleclik the tool to shange that to a line) See [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38779/how-to-select-a-small-portion-of-an-image-in-illustrator-cs6/58568#58568) or . But really sounds like you want a clipping mask.

Comment: What's wrong with the white stroke around the primary shape?? That seems to be performing what you want to perform. There's no real need to remove parts of the underlying paths below the white stroke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1

You can more easily create the "starburst" effect with a stroked path by drawing **one** path and using `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform`:

[image]

In the `Angle` field, merely enter `360/X` where `X` is the number of copies you want. **Illustrator will do the math for you** and determine what angle is necessary to fit `X` number of copies into a circle (360°). In the image above, I entered `360/50` and AI determined that 7.2° was necessary.

## 2

If you merely want to hide the lines, offset from the primary figure, you can add a **white stroke** (or whatever color matches the background) to the figure. The fact that things exist *under* each other shouldn't be an issue.

[image]

## 3

If you do indeed want to remove the paths with an offset, you *could* use a **Clipping Mask**.

Draw a path which encompasses all the "starburst" outside points. Then draw a path which is offset from the primary figure as far as you'd like this "gap" to be. Select *both* these paths and choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu.

[image]

Now select this compound path and the starburst lines and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.

[image]

This will simply *hide* the portions of the "starburst" which are *not* within the containing path.

## 4

If you *really* want to just remove the strokes around the primary figure, you *are* going to *have* to do some expanding to a degree.

You *can* take the clipping mask version above -- select the clipping mask and choose `Object > Expand` from the menu. Then merely hit the `Crop` button on the **Pathfinder Panel**. However, this *will* expand the strokes of the "starburst".

[image]

Or...

You can take a step back... Select the starburst (as created with the effect above) and choose `Object > Expand Appearance`. This will create individual paths for each "burst" and remove the live effect aspect.

Now, using a path that is offset from the primary figure, select that and these individual "starburst" paths. Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**, Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click-drag over anything you *don't* want.

[image]

This will remove parts of the strokes offset from the primary figure, but will also *keep them as stroked paths*.

By keeping the "bursts" as stroked paths, you can easily use the **Stroke Panel** to assign a *profile* to the strokes for more variations....

[image]

For my work, I generally prefer to use a clipping mask (#3) if a white outline (#2) doesn't suffice. I try not to be destructive and expand things unless I must.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Opacity Masks.

1. Move and group lines in a separate layer and human figure in another layer. Select solid shape and go to `Object > Path > Offset Path` to create another solid shape for masking. Fill it with black color. And cut it to clipboard.

[image]

[image]
2. Select lines layer and go to Transparency panel, click *Make Mask*. Uncheck *Clip*.   You'll see two previews. One has your lines, the one on right is black. Paste in Front the shape you had cut to clipboard. You'll see something like this.
[image]

[image]

3. This will also turn on Masking layers in Layers panel. To see all your layers again, click on left side of preview in Transparency Panel.

[image]

This should give you the result you want. If you want to go to Masking mode again, select the lines layer again and go to Transparency panel.

You can alter mask shape/lines later. For example, I increased the stroke lengths by selecting lines group. But for this, first you'll need to unlink mask from layer, by clicking the Link/Unlink button in Transparency panel. Once done, unlink it again.

[image]

Comment: What is your reason to suggest opacity mask here, rather than a clipping mask?

Comment: @Vincent I didn't know how to do it using clipping mask. But it's possible now I can think.

Comment: thanks guys!! <3

Comment: @Vincent you wanna write answer about clipping mask? And you meant the manual clipping mask that we make using Object Clipping > Mask > Make?

Comment: Scott has already incorporated it into his answer, so no need. :)

Comment: @Kyle thank you so much :)